# Error in caretTheme() : could not find function "caretTheme"

Tags: r, r-caret

Can somebody point me in the right direction here, I am using the caret package and I am trying to run a `caretTheme` but it keeps returning the error:

```
Error in caretTheme() : could not find function "caretTheme"
```

I tried install.packages('caretTheme') and receive the error

```
"Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘caretTheme’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1 Patched)"
```

I have searched on github and cannot find the package listed there or am I able to find it onlinee to bruteforce install using devtools::

Can you find the package available for download anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing developmental version:

```
devtools::install_github("topepo/caret/pkg/caret")

library(caret)
exists("caretTheme")

[1] TRUE

sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$caret$Version

"6.0-77"
```